# Why is direnv failing to read my zsh/fish/elvish/tcsh script?

Tags: zsh, fish, tcsh, direnv, elvish

When attempting to evaluate a `.envrc` file I get the error "`emulate: command not found`" or "`cd: -q: invalid option`" or any number of various possible errors in my completely valid `zsh`/`fish`/`elivsh`/`tcsh` script.

Comment: This problem drove me up a wall for several hours before I finally bothered the author on IRC.  He told me that many other people had the same issue.  So I figured I'd try to help with discoverability by posting a self-answer.

Comment: `attempting to use the following .envrc file` - did you forget to paste the file ?

Comment: Not quite.  I decided that making a block quote that just had `source myscript.zsh` wasn't terribly enlightening and too specific to a particular shell, so I restructured the question, but I missed editing that specific phrase.  Good catch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`direnv` uses only `bash` to evaluate your `.envrc` file.  It then exports the changes back to your original shell. You'll have to rewrite your `.envrc` in `bash`.

Also check out `direnv stdlib` for the utility functions that `direnv` gives you access to from within any `.envrc` file.